# Milestone graphic in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, metapost

> **This question led to a new project for a TikZ based solution:**
> [`timeline`](https://github.com/cfiandra/timeline)
>
> **The author of the original artwork has posted his METAPOST based library:**
> [`blueprint`](https://github.com/michipili/blueprint)

How could I implement a milestone graphic like this in TikZ?
[image: Milestones]

Several basic requirements:

1. Begin with some arbitrary data input (preferably JSON or CSV) defining the task list, level of effort, and timeline position.
2. Transparency effect used for task bubbles.
3. Description labels placed automatically.

Work in progress borrowed from the [Skype Example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/skype-topology/):

```
    % Timeline
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
    \PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

    \tikzstyle{task}=[circle,minimum width=20pt,fill opacity=0.5,fill=red]
    \tikzstyle{phase}=[circle,minimum width=20pt]
    \tikzstyle{legend}=[]
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      % Place tasks
      \foreach \place/\name in {{(0,0)/a},{(0.5,0)/b},{(1.0,0)/c},{(1.5,0)/d},{(2.0,0)/e}}
            \node[task] (\name) at \place {};
       %%%%%%%%
      \fill[black] (-.1,-.1) rectangle (2.1,0.1);
       % Legends
       \node[legend] at (0,-2) {Milestones};
       \node[legend] at (3,-2) {Involvement};
       \node[legend] at (0,2) {Project Milestones};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Which characteristics of the (quite complex) figure are important to you? Do you want to find an automated way of generating these kinds of graphics? If so, what's your data format? Do the labels need to be placed automatically?

Comment: We're looking to develop a better tool for capturing our software development milestones and this is possibly the best milestone figure I've found yet. We would like to automatically generate the figure based on some input data; possibly CSV or JSON. The bubble size, placement, and color would be good parameters to start with. I'm not sure where to start but I'll try to work on a MWE.

Comment: It's certainly possible to do this, but you will end up asking several more questions here regarding specific difficulties. That's going to happen once you have tried to break the figure down into smaller drawing problems.

Comment: A few suggestions to read up in the [pgfmanual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf): Part I, section 3 (Petri Net tutorial) for some basics. Part IV, section 46 (shadings) for those nice colours. Finally part VII, section 84 (transparency) to get those overlapping circles to work.

Comment: Note that I implemented the graphic in METAPOST, see https://bitbucket.org/michipili/blueprint — While METAPOST is not TIKZ, you might be interested.

Comment: Excellent! I'm so happy to hear from the original author! Well done! I'll give METAPOST a try.

Comment: @Jake Your personal information will still be available via the post history. If you want to remove it completely, maybe flag your post for mod attention. I think they have a retraction tool to remove stuff from the history.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

*The latest version of the timeline library can be find in the [`timeline repository`](https://github.com/cfiandra/timeline).*

This is a start of a solution, which provides the experimental `timeline` library.

The library introduces three main commands:

1. `\timeline` for drawing a rectangle with the number of weeks;
2. `\phase` for drawing bubbles: `\phase`s have to be put in the proper `phases` environment;
3. `\addmilestone` for adding milestones to bubbles.

How to use the library?

At first one should declare the number of weeks the timeline spans: the weeks are placed deterministically on the timeline according to their number. The dimensions of the timeline can be customized through the keys `timeline width`, `timeline height` and `timeline offset` (which corresponds to the height of the thin shaded border). For example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[timeline offset=0.2]
```

For convenience, each week is a node and, as every node, can be accessed for later use; its name is `week-<number of the week>`; for instance:

```
\draw (week-1)--++(90:1cm);
```

will draw a line of 1cm above `Week 1`.

Then it's the turn of the phases: as stated, they can be inserted through the `\phase` command within the `phases` environment. This environment simply puts in the background layer its content so that the timeline will stay in the main layer. Each phase is characterized by a position, a degree and a color; for each property there is a key. The position can be set by `between week=<initial> and <end> in <offset>` where `<intial>` is the beginning week, `<end>` the ending week and `<offset>` is a number from 0 to 1 which sets the distance from `<initial>` to `<end>`. The `involvement degree` simply sets the radius of the bubble while `phase color` its color. As well as the weeks, also the phases have an id in the form `phase-<number>`: it will be useful later on. The `<number>` is progressive, meaning that it increases each time one adds a `phase`.

Last, but not least, the milestones. They can be added through the `\addmilestone` command, which need: a starting position, a direction where the line will go and a text. For the starting position, use the `at` key, and I suggest to exploit the phase name, i.e. `at=phase-1.north` (after the dotuse whatever TikZ allows). The `direction` can be something like `90:1cm` and the `text` sets the label. Some customization of the text can be done through the `text options` key.

The code of the library:

```
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  timeline width/.store in=\timelinewidth,
  timeline width=20,
  timeline height/.store in=\timelineheight,
  timeline height=1,
  timeline offset/.store in=\timelineoffset,
  timeline offset=0.15,
  initial week/.store in=\initialweek,
  initial week=1,
  end week/.store in=\endweek,
  end week=2,
  time point/.store in=\timepoint,
  time point=0.5,
  between week/.style args={#1 and #2 in #3}{
    initial week=#1,
    end week=#2,
    time point=#3,
  },  
  involvement degree/.store in=\involvdegree,
  involvement degree=2cm,
  phase color/.store in=\phasecol,
  phase color=red!50!orange,
  phase appearance/.style={
    circle,
    opacity=0.3,
    minimum size=\involvdegree,
    fill=\phasecol
  },
}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/milestone/.cd,
  at/.store in=\msstartpoint,
  at=phase-1.north,
  circle radius/.store in=\milestonecircleradius,
  circle radius=0.1cm,
  direction/.store in=\msdirection,
  direction=90:2cm,
  text/.store in=\mstext,
  text={},
  text options/.code={\tikzset{#1}},
}


\newcommand{\timeline}[1]{
  \draw[fill,opacity=0.8] (0,0) rectangle (\timelinewidth,\timelineheight);
  \shade[top color=black, bottom color=white,middle color=black!20]
    (0,0) rectangle (\timelinewidth,-\timelineoffset);
  \shade[top color=white, bottom color=black,middle color=black!20]  
    (0,\timelineheight) rectangle (\timelinewidth,\timelineheight+\timelineoffset);

  \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {1,...,#1}  {\global\let\maxsmitem\xi} 

  \pgfmathsetmacro\position{\timelinewidth/(\maxsmitem+1)} 
  \node at (0,0.5\timelineheight)(week-0){\phantom{Week 0}}; 

  \foreach \x[count=\xi] in {1,...,#1}{
       \node[text=white]at +(\xi*\position,0.5\timelineheight) (week-\xi) {Week \x};
  }
}

\newcounter{involv}
\setcounter{involv}{0}

\newcommand{\phase}[1]{
\stepcounter{involv}
\node[phase appearance,#1] 
 (phase-\theinvolv)
 at ($(week-\initialweek)!\timepoint!(week-\endweek)$){};
}

\newcommand{\initialphase}[1]{
\node[phase appearance,#1,anchor=west,between week=0 and 1 in 0,] 
 (phase-\theinvolv)
 at ($(week-0)!0!(week-1)$){};
\setcounter{involv}{0} 
}

\newenvironment{phases}{\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}}{\end{pgfonlayer}}

\newcommand{\addmilestone}[1]{
\pgfkeys{/tikz/milestone/.cd,#1}
\draw[double,fill] (\msstartpoint) circle [radius=\milestonecircleradius];
\draw(\msstartpoint)--++(\msdirection)node[/tikz/milestone/text options]{\mstext};
}
```

A document example:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{timeline}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\timeline{8}% number of weeks

% put here the phases
\begin{phases}
\initialphase{involvement degree=1.75cm,phase color=black}
\phase{between week=1 and 2 in 0.1,involvement degree=2.25cm}
\phase{between week=1 and 2 in 0.5,involvement degree=3cm}
\phase{between week=1 and 2 in 0.9,involvement degree=2.125cm}
\phase{between week=3 and 4 in 0.7,phase color=blue!80!cyan}
\end{phases}

% put here the milestones
\addmilestone{at=phase-0.90,direction=90:1cm,text={Initial meeting},text options={above}}
\addmilestone{at=phase-0.270,direction=270:1cm,text={Initial meeting},text options={below}}

\addmilestone{at=phase-2.110,direction=120:1.5cm,text={Research},text options={above}}
\addmilestone{at=phase-2.250,direction=240:1.5cm,text={Need Agreement},text options={below}}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Wow. Did you just do that on a whim? Amazing

Comment: @Leeser: glad you like it :) There's still lot of room for improvements, though.

Comment: @JakeHertenstein: :)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Is the fact that it measures time in weeks hard-coded in a way which would make the library difficult to adapt for more general use? I want to draw a timeline covering thousands of years and it needs to fit on A4... Looks by far the most beautiful timeline I've seen from TeX, though ;). Also, could you please clarify the licence of your github code?

Comment: I hope you don't mind. I started with the code you used for the centre of the time line (the thick black line and the fading borders above and below). And then, I... er... sort of made a bunch of different stuff up. It was a really useful beginning even though the rest of my timeline looks rather different! (I needed to span around 500 BCE to roughly present day which doesn't work well with weeks and I would have had way too many circles and then I decided to add this and that...) Thanks and I hope you won't mind the monstrosity you inspired. (The monstrousness is all of my making!)

Comment: @cfr: I'm sorry to not have seen your previous comment (during last weekend I was travelling). The code is actually put under the LPPL licence (see [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/4524/13304)). For what concern the timespan, I already realized that: a) having only weeks is not good, b) hardcoding the number of weeks is not good as well. Indeed, you can see from the code on github and, even better, from the linked Q/A "How do I develop a complex time line?" that these constraints have been relaxed. For the shapes, it is a difficult to decide which is the best one. ->

Comment: -> Indeed, circles seem to be fine if they do not overlap too much, while the trapeziums seem to be fine if their height in the timeline is comparable. I'm planning to extend this work to a package, but I need some time: if you are interested to share you contribution (we might want to discuss via mail or in chat), I will be very happy to collaborate.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I'd be happy to discuss this further or share my code. (But my code is rather kludgey and I'm not sure how well it would fit since it does something rather different after the beginning. Basically, I have just the borders of the time line coloured with overlapping rectangles and the coloured nodes sprouting off from the timeline with details of the person involved. This allows me to stack the nodes above and below the timeline when things get densely packed.)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Would you consider adding an LPPL licence statement to your files on Git Hub? Right now, your statement here covers the version posted above but it says nothing about the updated versions you post there. Moreover, including the licence in the source is much more robust and makes it much easier for people with no connection here to determine the licence. I speak as somebody who did at one time put in hours of work attempting to trace the authors of packages in TeX Live. Some packages just ended up being removed...

Comment: @cfr: Indeed you're right. It seems yesterday I forgot to add the licence while updating. Thanks :)

Comment: @cfr: Could you provide a link to your project?

Comment: @JakeHertenstein Well, I don't actually have it anywhere but on my computer right now. Why?

Comment: @JakeHertenstein If you just want to see the PDF, you can find it [here](http://cfrees.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/timeline-orig.pdf).

Comment: @cfr, I'm way impressed! Might I suggest that you publish your excellent work. I was curious to see how you adapted the example for inspiring ideas of my own on how to extend these libraries. It seems you have the most complicated timeline I've ever seen!

Comment: @JakeHertenstein To be honest, I'm not sure what to do with it. It is rather... idiosyncratic, I think.

Comment: @JakeHertenstein See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215082/...

Answer (score 17):

Some initial ideas here:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[week/.style={font=\bfseries, text=white},
initial_contact/.style={fill=black!60,circle,opacity=0.5},
planning/.style={fill=red,circle,opacity=0.5},
content/.style={fill=yellow,circle,opacity=0.5} ]


%%%%% Tasks
% Initial phase
\node[initial_contact, minimum size=4em] at (-2, 0) {};

% Planning phase
\node[planning, minimum size=7em] at (0, 0) {};
\node[planning, minimum size=15em] at (3, 0) {};
\node[planning, minimum size=7em] at (5, 0) {};

% Content phase
\node[content, minimum size=7em] at (10, 0) {};

\filldraw[fill=black, draw=white,line width=1ex,opacity=0.75] (-3.5,-0.5) rectangle (54,0.5);
%%%%% Weeks.
\node[week] at (0,0) {WEEK1};
\node[week] at (7,0) {WEEK2};
\node[week] at (14,0) {WEEK3};
\node[week] at (21,0) {WEEK4};
\node[week] at (28,0) {WEEK5};
\node[week] at (35,0) {WEEK6};
\node[week] at (42,0) {WEEK7};
\node[week] at (49,0) {WEEK8};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

- The weeks are located at 0, 7, 14, etc. So, if week1 (at 0,0) started yesterday (Monday 10) and you have a task on Friday 14, the position of the task would be (4, 0).
- I've made a node for every phase, maybe this could be improved.
- For the loops and the label, I'm going to steal something from @ClaudioFiandrino :P

[image]

EDIT: Reading tasks from file, adding labels

So, now I read the tasks from a file.
The file format is a CSV with phase, taskid, name, position (0 for first week, 7 for the second week, 3.5 for the middle of the first week, etc) and size. The output is the same as before. Right now I put the label in a fixed position. I cannot think of an automatic way of positioning a label without overlapping.

Labels are re-sized according to size.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{tasks.dat}
phase,taskid,name,position,size
initial,initialmeeting,Initial Meeting,-2,4
planning,needsassesment,Needs Assesment,0,7
planning,research,Research,3,15
planning,siteoutline,Site Outline,5,7
content,contentoutline,Content Outline,10,7
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb[noheader=false]{tasks}{tasks.dat}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[week/.style={font=\bfseries, text=white},
initial/.style={fill=black!60,circle,opacity=0.5},
planning/.style={fill=red,circle,opacity=0.5},
content/.style={fill=yellow,circle,opacity=0.5} ]

%%%%% Tasks
\DTLforeach*{tasks}{\phase=phase, \taskid=taskid, \name=name, \position=position,\size=size}{\node(\taskid)[\phase, minimum size=\size em] at (\position, 0) {};
\draw (node cs:name=\taskid, anchor=north) to ++(0,3) node[above, scale=\size/6] {\name};
}


\filldraw[fill=black, draw=white,line width=1ex,opacity=0.75] (-3.5,-0.5) rectangle (54,0.5);

%%%%% Weeks.
\node[week] at (0,0) {WEEK1};
\node[week] at (7,0) {WEEK2};
\node[week] at (14,0) {WEEK3};
\node[week] at (21,0) {WEEK4};
\node[week] at (28,0) {WEEK5};
\node[week] at (35,0) {WEEK6};
\node[week] at (42,0) {WEEK7};
\node[week] at (49,0) {WEEK8};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]