# Chronosys printing measurement units

Tags: chronosys

I'm using the chronosys (http://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/macros/latex/contrib/chronosys/docchronosys_en.pdf) package to prepare a timeline with the code below.
1) This code is printing a line at the top of the page that is showing the conversion from points to inches [image: Document]. How do I supress this?
2) How do I get the textwidth option to work to have the text of the events wrap?
3) Lastly, is there a way to build in a bit of whitespace between the timeline and the vertical mark leading to the event name?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chronosys}
\begin{document} 
\begin{chronology}[startyear=1995, stopyear=2008]
\chronograduation[periode]{1}
\chronoevent[markdepth=5, year=false, textwidth=1cm]{1995}{Debate on CEPA Begins}
\chronoevent[markdepth=15, year=false]{1999}{CEPA Amendments Passed}
\chronoevent[markdepth=15, year=false]{2007}{BPA Risk Assessment Begins}
\chronoevent[markdepth=5, year=false]{2006}{Categorization of DSL}

\end{chronology}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The value of `markdepth` must be a dimen not a number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chronosys}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document} 
\begin{chronology}[startyear=1995, stopyear=2008]
\chronograduation[periode]{1}
\chronoevent[markdepth=20pt, year=false, textwidth=1cm]{1995}{Debate on CEPA Begins}
\chronoevent[markdepth=50pt, year=false]{1999}{\parbox{2.5cm}{\RaggedRight{CEPA Amendments Passed this is a long label}}}
\chronoevent[markdepth=50pt, year=false]{2007}{BPA Risk Assessment Begins}
\chronoevent[markdepth=20pt, year=false]{2006}{Categorization of DSL}
\end{chronology}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In terms of your "gap" I would move the scale to the top like this (choice of colors is yours -- you could make all black)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chronosys}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document} 
\begin{chronology}[startyear=1995, stopyear=2008]
\chronoperiodecoloralternation{black,green,black,green}
\chronograduation[periode][dateselevation=0pt]{1}
\chronoevent[markdepth=20pt, year=false, textwidth=1cm]{1995}{Debate on CEPA Begins}
\chronoevent[markdepth=50pt, year=false]{1999}{\parbox{2.5cm}{\RaggedRight{CEPA Amendments Passed this is a long label}}}
\chronoevent[markdepth=50pt, year=false]{2007}{BPA Risk Assessment Begins}
\chronoevent[markdepth=20pt, year=false]{2006}{Categorization of DSL}
\end{chronology}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A new version (slightly amended) of *chronos*. The code is only as long as it is because it is attempting to become a more flexible substitute for `chronosys`, which is extremely problematic in many ways. (If it does exactly what you want, great. If you want to tweak it a little, good luck.)

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}
\usepackage{datenumber,xparse,fp}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,backgrounds,fixedpointarithmetic}
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_chronos_date_tl
\tl_new:N \l_chronos_dateformat_tl
\tl_new:N \l_chronos_year_tl
\tl_new:N \l_chronos_yearformat_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_chronos_dateformat_tl { !d/!m/!Y }
\tl_set:Nn \l_chronos_yearformat_tl { !Y }
% YY yn lle YYYY
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \chronos_year_shorten:n #1
{
  \chronos_year_shorten_aux:w #1 \q_stop % expl3 manuaal, 46
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \chronos_year_shorten_aux:w #1 #2 #3 #4 \q_stop
{
  #3 #4
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \chronos_year_shorten:n { V , c }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_abs:n { c }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn { Nnx }
% dangos dyddiadau
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \chronos_show_date:n #1
{% ateb Joseph Wright: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327642/
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l_chronos_date_tl \l_chronos_dateformat_tl
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_date_tl { !a } { \pgfcalendarweekdayshortname{\thechronos@weekday} }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_date_tl { !A } { \pgfcalendarweekdayname{\thechronos@weekday} }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_date_tl { !b } { \pgfcalendarmonthshortname{\csname chronos@#1month\endcsname} }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_date_tl { !B } { \pgfcalendarmonthname{\csname chronos@#1month\endcsname} }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_date_tl { !d } { \csname chronos@#1day\endcsname }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_date_tl { !E } { \chronos_dateformat_era:c { chronos@#1year } }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_date_tl { !m } { \csname chronos@#1month\endcsname }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_date_tl { !q } { \chronos_dateformat_sign:c { chronos@#1year } }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_date_tl { !Q } { \chronos_dateformat_signs:c { chronos@#1year } }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_date_tl { !y } { \chronos_year_shorten:c { chronos@#1year } }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_date_tl { !Y } { \int_abs:c { chronos@#1year } }
  \l_chronos_date_tl
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \chronos_show_year:n #1
{% ateb Joseph Wright: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327642/
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l_chronos_year_tl \l_chronos_yearformat_tl
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_year_tl { !E } { \chronos_dateformat_era:n { #1 } }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_year_tl { !q } { \chronos_dateformat_sign:n { #1 } }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_year_tl { !Q } { \chronos_dateformat_signs:n { #1 } }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_year_tl { !y } { \chronos_year_shorten:n { #1 } }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_year_tl { !Y } { \int_abs:n { #1 } }
  \l_chronos_year_tl
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \chronos_dateformat_sign:n #1
{
  \int_compare:nT { #1 < 0 } { - }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \chronos_dateformat_sign:n { c }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \chronos_dateformat_signs:n #1
{
  \int_compare:nTF
  { #1 < 0 } { - }
  {
    \int_compare:nT { #1 > 0 }
    {
      \ifchronos@yearzero\relax
      \else
        \int_compare:nT { #1 > 1} { +  }
      \fi
    }
  }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \chronos_dateformat_signs:n { c }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \chronos_dateformat_era:n #1
{
  \int_compare:nTF
  { #1 < 0 } { \chronos@yearbce }
  {
    \int_compare:nT { #1 > 0 }
    {
      \ifchronos@yearzero\relax
      \else
        \int_compare:nT { #1 > 1} { \chronos@yearce }
      \fi
    }
  }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \chronos_dateformat_era:n { c }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \chronos_set_dateformat:n #1
{
  \tl_set:Nn \l_chronos_dateformat_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_chronos_dateformat_tl { ~ } { \c_space_token }
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \chronos_set_yearformat:n #1
{
  \tl_set:Nn \l_chronos_yearformat_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_chronos_yearformat_tl { ~ } { \c_space_token }
}
% user interface
\NewDocumentCommand \chronos@setdateformat { m }
{
  \chronos_set_dateformat:n { #1 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand \chronos@setyearformat { m }
{
  \chronos_set_yearformat:n { #1 }
}
% for pgf/tikz convenience
\NewDocumentCommand \chronos@showdate { o m }
{
  \group_begin:
    \IfValueT { #1 }
    {
      \chronos_set_dateformat:n { #1 }
    }
    \pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\csname thechronos@#2date\endcsname}{\c@chronos@weekday}%
    \chronos_show_date:n { #2 }
  \group_end:
}
\NewDocumentCommand \chronos@showyear { o m }
{
  \group_begin:
    \IfValueT { #1 }
    {
      \chronos_set_yearformat:n { #1 }
    }
    \chronos_show_year:n { #2 }
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newlength\chronos@tempdima
\newcounter{chronos@date}
\newcounter{chronos@startdate}
\newcounter{chronos@enddate}
\newcounter{chronos@startyear}
\newcounter{chronos@endyear}
\newcounter{chronos@yeardate}
\newcounter{chronos@thingdate}
\newcounter{chronos@otherthingdate}
\newcounter{chronos@weekday}
\newcounter{chronos@tempcnta}
\newif\ifchronos@marks
\chronos@marksfalse
\newif\ifchronos@timeline@showyears
\chronos@timeline@showyearstrue
\newif\ifchronos@eventyearsonline
\chronos@eventyearsonlinefalse
\newif\ifchronos@yearzero
\chronos@yearzerofalse
\newif\ifchronos@onlytext
\chronos@onlytextfalse
\newif\ifchronos@markeras
\chronos@markerasfalse
\newif\ifchronos@yearsonline
\chronos@yearsonlinefalse
\newif\ifchronos@eventdatessplit
\chronos@eventdatessplitfalse
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format,
  int detect,
  set thousands separator={},
}
\tikzset{%
  /handlers/.chronos too/.code={%
    \edef\chronos@tempc{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}%
    \edef\chronos@tempd{#1}%
    \tikzset{%
      \pgfkeyscurrentpath @too/.code={%
        \tikzset{%
          /chronos/\chronos@tempd/.append style={##1},
        }%
      },
      \chronos@tempc/.forward to=\chronos@tempc @too,
    }%
  },
  chronos/.code={% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159856/ - Claudio Fiandrino
    \tikzset{%
      align=center,
      anchor=mid,
      fixed point arithmetic,
      /chronos/.cd,
      #1,
      timeline config,
      timeline config/.code={},
    }%
    \ifnum\chronos@startyear=\chronos@endyear
      \tikzset{%
        /chronos/timeline no years,
      }%
    \fi
    \setlength\chronos@tempdima{\chronos@timelinemargin}%
    \ifchronos@markeras
      {%
        \chronos@timelinefont
        \pgfmathsetmacro\chronos@tempe{((width("\chronos@bce"))>(width("\chronos@ce"))) ? (width("\chronos@bce")) : (width("\chronos@ce"))}%
        \xdef\chronos@tempf{\chronos@tempe}%
      }%
      \addtolength\chronos@tempdima{\chronos@tempf pt}%
    \fi
    \pgfmathsetmacro\chronos@unit{(\chronos@width-2*\chronos@tempdima)/(\thechronos@enddate-\thechronos@startdate)}%
    \draw [/chronos/timeline@line, line width=\chronos@height] (-\chronos@tempdima,0) coordinate (chronos pre) -- +(\chronos@width,0) coordinate (chronos post);
    \coordinate (chronos base) at (0,-.5*\chronos@height);
    \coordinate (chronos top) at (0,.5*\chronos@height);
    \coordinate (chronos foot) at (0,{-.5*\chronos@height-\chronos@borderheight});
    \coordinate (chronos head) at (0,{.5*\chronos@height+\chronos@borderheight});
    \coordinate (chronos start) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (chronos end) at ([xshift=-\chronos@tempdima]chronos post);
    \ifdim\chronos@borderheight>0pt
      \fill [bottom color=chronos@borderinner, top color=chronos@borderouter] (chronos pre |- chronos head) rectangle (chronos post |- chronos top);
      \fill [top color=chronos@borderinner, bottom color=chronos@borderouter] (chronos pre |- chronos base) rectangle (chronos post |- chronos foot);
    \fi
    \ifchronos@timeline@showyears
      \pgfmathsetcounter{chronos@startyear}{\chronos@startyear}%
      \pgfmathsetcounter{chronos@endyear}{\chronos@endyear}%
      \def\tempa{none}%
      \ifx\chronos@stepfrom\tempa
        \def\tempa{01}%
        \ifx\chronos@startmonth\tempa
          \ifx\chronos@startday\tempa
            \else\stepcounter{chronos@startyear}%
          \fi
          \else\stepcounter{chronos@startyear}%
        \fi
      \else
        \pgfmathsetcounter{chronos@startyear}{\chronos@stepfrom}%
      \fi
      \def\tempa{12}%
      \def\tempb{31}%
      \ifx\chronos@endmonth\tempa
        \ifx\chronos@endday\tempb
          \stepcounter{chronos@endyear}%
        \fi
      \fi
      \ifnum\value{chronos@endyear}<\value{chronos@startyear}\setcounter{chronos@endyear}{\thechronos@startyear}\fi
      \pgfmathsetmacro\chronos@nextstep{int(((\thechronos@startyear+\chronos@stepyears)>\thechronos@endyear) ? \thechronos@endyear : (\thechronos@startyear+\chronos@stepyears))}%
      \ifchronos@yearzero\setcounter{chronos@tempcnta}{1}\else\setcounter{chronos@tempcnta}{0}\fi
      \foreach \b [evaluate=\b as \i using {((\b==0)&&(\thechronos@tempcnta==0)) ? 1 : int(\b)}, remember=\i as \ilast (initially \pi)] in {\thechronos@startyear,\chronos@nextstep,...,\thechronos@endyear} {%
        \ifnum\i=\ilast\relax
        \else
          \pgfcalendardatetojulian{{\i}-01-01}{\c@chronos@yeardate}%
          \ifchronos@yearzero\relax\else\ifnum0<\i\addtocounter{chronos@yeardate}{-366}\fi\fi
          \pgfmathsetmacro\chronos@tempa{(\thechronos@yeardate-\thechronos@startdate)*\chronos@unit}%
          \ifchronos@yearsonline
            \node (chronos@year@\i) [/chronos/.cd, timeline@years, timeline year on line] at (\chronos@tempa pt,0) {\chronos@timelinefont\chronos@showyear{\i}};
            \ifchronos@marks
               \path [/chronos/timeline mark on line] (chronos@year@\i.south) -- (chronos@year@\i |- chronos base);
               \path [/chronos/timeline mark on line] (chronos@year@\i.north) --  (chronos@year@\i |- chronos top);
            \fi
            \ifchronos@markeras
              \path (chronos pre) +(\chronos@timelinemargin,0) node (chronos@bce) [/chronos/.cd, timeline@years, timeline year on line] {\chronos@timelinefont\chronos@bce};
              \path (chronos post) +(-\chronos@timelinemargin,0) node (chronos@ce) [/chronos/.cd, timeline@years, timeline year on line] {\chronos@timelinefont\chronos@ce};
            \fi
          \else
            \node (chronos@year@\i) [/chronos/.cd, timeline@years, timeline year off line] at (\chronos@tempa pt,0) {\chronos@timelinefont\chronos@showyear{\i}};
            \ifchronos@marks
              \path [shorten <=.5*\chronos@height, /chronos/timeline mark off line] (\chronos@tempa pt, 0) -- (chronos@year@\i);
            \fi
            \ifchronos@markeras
              \path (chronos pre) +(\chronos@timelinemargin,0) node (chronos@bce) [/chronos/.cd, timeline@years, timeline year off line] {\chronos@timelinefont\chronos@bce};
              \path (chronos post) +(-\chronos@timelinemargin,0) node (chronos@ce) [/chronos/.cd, timeline@years, timeline year off line] {\chronos@timelinefont\chronos@ce};
            \fi
          \fi
        \fi
      }%
    \else
      \ifchronos@markeras
        \path (chronos pre) +(\chronos@timelinemargin,0) node (chronos@bce) [/chronos/.cd, timeline@years, timeline year off line] {\chronos@timelinefont\chronos@bce};
        \path (chronos post) +(-\chronos@timelinemargin,0) node (chronos@ce) [/chronos/.cd, timeline@years, timeline year off line] {\chronos@timelinefont\chronos@ce};
      \fi
    \fi
    \ifchronos@eventyearsonline
      \tikzset{%
        /chronos/timeline years=on line,
      }%
    \fi
  },
  chronos set date/.code args={#1:#2:#3:#4}{%
    \pgfcalendardatetojulian{{#1}-#2-#3}{\c@chronos@date}%
    \setcounter{chronos@#4date}{\thechronos@date}%
    \ifchronos@yearzero\relax
    \else
      \setcounter{chronos@tempcnta}{#1}%
      \ifnum0<\value{chronos@tempcnta}%
        \addtocounter{chronos@#4date}{-366}%
      \fi
    \fi
    \expandafter\def\csname chronos@#4year\endcsname{#1}%
    \expandafter\def\csname chronos@#4month\endcsname{#2}%
    \expandafter\def\csname chronos@#4day\endcsname{#3}%
  },
  chronos date/.style args={#1-#2-#3}{%
    /tikz/chronos set date/.expanded={#1:#2:#3:thing}%
  },
  chronos period date/.style args={#1-#2-#3}{%
    /tikz/chronos set date/.expanded={#1:#2:#3:otherthing}%
  },
  /chronos/.search also={/tikz},
  /chronos/.cd,
  timeline config/.code={},
  date format/.code={%
    \chronos@setdateformat{#1}%
  },
  year format/.code={%
    \chronos@setyearformat{#1}%
  },
  step years/.store in=\chronos@stepyears,
  step from year/.store in=\chronos@stepfrom,
  start date/.style args={#1-#2-#3}{%
    /chronos/timeline config/.append code={%
      \tikzset{/tikz/chronos set date/.expanded={#1:#2:#3:start}}%
    },
  },
  end date/.style args={#1-#2-#3}{%
    /chronos/timeline config/.append code={%
      \tikzset{/tikz/chronos set date/.expanded={#1:#2:#3:end}}%
    },
  },
  ce year label/.store in=\chronos@yearce,
  bce year label/.store in=\chronos@yearbce,
  timeline ce label/.store in=\chronos@ce,
  timeline bce label/.store in=\chronos@bce,
  timeline width/.store in=\chronos@width,
  timeline height/.store in=\chronos@height,
  width/.forward to=/chronos/timeline width,
  height/.forward to=/chronos/timeline height,
  timeline border height/.store in=\chronos@borderheight,
  timeline border inner colour/.code={\colorlet{chronos@borderinner}{#1}},
  timeline border outer colour/.code={\colorlet{chronos@borderouter}{#1}},
  timeline mark eras/.is if=chronos@markeras,
  timeline margin/.store in=\chronos@timelinemargin,
  timeline font/.store in=\chronos@timelinefont,
  timeline years set/.store in=\chronos@timelineyears,
  timeline years/.is choice,
  timeline years/.forward to=/chronos/timeline years set,
  timeline years/above/.code={%
    \tikzset{%
      /chronos/timeline@years/.style={above, anchor=south, yshift=.5*\chronos@height},
    }%
  },
  timeline years/below/.code={%
    \tikzset{%
      /chronos/timeline@years/.style={below, anchor=north, yshift=-.5*\chronos@height},
    }%
  },
  timeline years/on line/.code={%
    \chronos@yearsonlinetrue
    \tikzset{%
      /chronos/timeline@years/.style={anchor=center},
    }%
  },
  only years/.code={%
    \edef\tempa{}%
    \edef\tempb{#1}%
    \ifx\tempa\tempb\chronos@setdateformat{!Y}\else\chronos@setdateformat{#1}\fi
    \tikzset{%
      /tikz/chronos date/.style={%
        /tikz/chronos set date/.expanded={##1:01:01:thing}%
      },
      /tikz/chronos period date/.style={%
        /tikz/chronos set date/.expanded={##1:01:01:otherthing}%
      },
    }%
  },
  only text/.code={%
    \tikzset{/chronos/only years}%
    \chronos@setdateformat{}%
    \chronos@onlytexttrue
  },
  year zero/.is if=chronos@yearzero,
  background/.code={%
    \colorlet{chronos@background}{#1}%
  },
  timeline marks/.is if=chronos@marks,
  timeline show years/.is if=chronos@timeline@showyears,
  timeline no years/.code={%
    \tikzset{%
      /chronos/timeline show years=false,
    }%
  },
  lines/.style={draw, {Triangle[width=0pt 3,reversed,length=0pt 1.5]}-{Triangle[width=0pt 3,reversed,length=0pt 1.5]}, shorten <={.5*\chronos@height+\chronos@borderheight}},
  events/.style={fill=chronos@background, fill opacity=.75, text opacity=1, draw opacity=1, rounded corners, align=center, font=\footnotesize},
  period/.style={draw},
  period event line/.style={/chronos/lines},
  period event/.style={/chronos/events},
  event line/.style={/chronos/lines},
  event/.style={/chronos/events},
  event years on line/.is if=chronos@eventyearsonline,
  event year on line/.style={/chronos/timeline@years, /chronos/timeline year on line},
  event dates split/.is if=chronos@eventdatessplit,
  event date split/.style={/chronos/event},
  event distance/.store in=\chronos@eventdistance,
  special date/.store in=\chronos@specialdate,
  timeline@line/.style={draw},
  timeline line/.chronos too=timeline@line,
  timeline year off line/.style={fill=chronos@background, text opacity=1, align=center, fill opacity=.75},
  timeline mark off line/.style={draw, {Triangle[width=0pt 3,reversed,length=0pt 1.5]}-, thin, shorten >=-2pt},
  timeline year on line/.style={text=chronos@background, inner sep=1pt, align=center},
  timeline mark on line/.style={draw=chronos@background, shorten >=1.5pt},
  timeline mark too/.code={%
    \tikzset{%
      /chronos/.cd,
      timeline mark on line/.append style={#1},
      timeline mark off line/.append style={#1},
    }%
  },
  timeline year too/.code={%
    \tikzset{%
      /chronos/.cd,
      timeline year on line/.append style={#1},
      timeline year off line/.append style={#1},
    }%
  },
  timeline mark/.forward to=/chronos/timeline mark too,
  timeline year/.forward to=/chronos/timeline year too,
  start date=1001-10-01,
  end date=1003-06-14,
  timeline width=100mm,
  timeline height=1pt,
  timeline border height=0pt,
  chronos date=1850-01-01,
  chronos period date=1851-01-01,
  step years=1,
  timeline years=above,
  background=white,
  timeline border inner colour=black,
  timeline border outer colour=chronos@background,
  step from year=none,
  special date=none,
  ce year label={\textsc{ce}},
  bce year label={\textsc{bce}},
  event distance=-10pt,
  timeline ce label={CE},
  timeline bce label={BCE},
  timeline margin=10pt,
  timeline font=\sffamily,
}
\NewDocumentCommand \chronosevent { O {} m O {} +m D () { \chronos@eventdistance } }
{%
  \tikzset{%
    chronos date/.expanded={#2},
  }%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\chronos@offset{(#5 < 0pt) ? (#5-.5*\chronos@height-\chronos@borderheight) : (#5+.5*\chronos@height+\chronos@borderheight)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\chronos@anchor{(#5 < 0pt) ? "north" : "south"}%
  \scoped[on background layer]{%
    \ifchronos@eventdatessplit
      \ifchronos@onlytext\relax
      \else
        \pgfmathsetmacro\chronos@invanchor{(#5 < 0pt) ? "south" : "north"}%
        \path [postaction={/chronos/event line, #1}] ({(\thechronos@thingdate-\thechronos@startdate)*\chronos@unit pt},0) -- +(0,-\chronos@offset pt) node [anchor=\chronos@invanchor, /chronos/event date split, #3] {\chronos@showdate{thing}};
      \fi
      \path [postaction={/chronos/event line, #1}] ({(\thechronos@thingdate-\thechronos@startdate)*\chronos@unit pt},0) -- +(0,\chronos@offset pt) node [anchor=\chronos@anchor, /chronos/event, #3] {#4};
    \else
      \path [postaction={/chronos/event line, #1}] ({(\thechronos@thingdate-\thechronos@startdate)*\chronos@unit pt},0) -- +(0,\chronos@offset pt) node [anchor=\chronos@anchor, /chronos/event, #3] {\ifchronos@onlytext\relax\else\chronos@showdate{thing}\\\fi#4};
    \fi
  }%
  \ifchronos@eventyearsonline
    \edef\tempa{none}%
    \edef\tempb{\chronos@specialdate}%
    \ifx\tempa\tempb\else\let\chronos@thingyear\chronos@specialdate\tikzset{/chronos/special date=none}\fi
    \node [/chronos/.cd, event year on line] at ({(\thechronos@thingdate-\thechronos@startdate)*\chronos@unit pt},0) {\chronos@thingyear};
  \fi
}
\NewDocumentCommand \chronosspecialdate { m }
{%
  \tikzset{%
    /chronos/special date=#1,
  }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand \chronosperiod { O {} m O {} m O {} +m D () { \chronos@eventdistance } }
{%
  \tikzset{%
    chronos date/.expanded={#2}, chronos period date/.expanded={#4}
  }%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\chronos@offset{(#7 < 0pt) ? (#7-.5*\chronos@height-\chronos@borderheight) : (#7+.5*\chronos@height+\chronos@borderheight)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\chronos@anchor{(#7 < 0pt) ? "north" : "south"}%
  \ifchronos@yearsonline
    \pgfmathsetmacro\chronos@borderoffset{(#7 < 0pt) ? (-.5*\chronos@height-.5*\chronos@borderheight) : (.5*\chronos@height+.5*\chronos@borderheight)}%
    \path [postaction={line width=\chronos@borderheight, /chronos/period, blend mode=overlay, #1}] ({(\thechronos@thingdate-\thechronos@startdate)*\chronos@unit pt},\chronos@borderoffset pt) -- ({(\thechronos@otherthingdate-\thechronos@startdate)*\chronos@unit pt},\chronos@borderoffset pt);
  \else
    \path [postaction={line width=\chronos@height, /chronos/period, #1}] ({(\thechronos@thingdate-\thechronos@startdate)*\chronos@unit pt},0) -- ({(\thechronos@otherthingdate-\thechronos@startdate)*\chronos@unit pt},0);
  \fi
  \scoped[on background layer]{\path [postaction={/chronos/period event line, #3}] ({(.5*\thechronos@otherthingdate+.5*\thechronos@thingdate-\thechronos@startdate)*\chronos@unit pt},0) -- +(0,\chronos@offset pt) node [anchor=\chronos@anchor, /chronos/period event, #5] {\ifchronos@onlytext\relax\else\chronos@showdate{thing}--\chronos@showdate{otherthing}\\\fi#6};}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    chronos={%
      timeline width=100mm,
      timeline height=2mm,
      start date=1995-01-01,
      end date=2008-01-01,
      only years,
      events/.append style={text width=20mm},
      timeline line={shorten >=-10mm, -{Triangle Cap[length=10mm]}},
      timeline font=\footnotesize,
      timeline marks,
      only text,
    }
  ]
  \chronosevent{1995}{Debate on CEPA Begins}(-5pt)
  \chronosevent{1999}{CEPA Amendments Passed}(-15pt)
  \chronosevent{2007}[text width=30mm]{BPA Risk Assessment Begins}(-30pt)
  \chronosevent{2006}{Categorization of DSL}(-5pt)
  \path [every node/.style={font=\large\bfseries\sffamily}] (chronos start |- current bounding box.north) node (n) [above] {1995} (chronos end |- n) node {2008};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    chronos={%
      timeline width=100mm,
      start date=1995-01-01,
      end date=2008-01-01,
      events/.append style={text width=20mm},
      timeline font=\footnotesize,
      timeline marks,
      timeline height=5mm,
      only text,
      timeline years=on line,
      timeline border height=5pt,
    },
    my box/.style={draw=#1, rounded corners, text=#1, thick},
  ]
  \chronosevent[blue]{1995}[my box=blue]{Debate on CEPA Begins}(-5pt)
  \chronosevent[green!75!black]{1999}[my box=green!75!black]{CEPA Amendments Passed}(-15pt)
  \chronosevent[magenta]{2007}[text width=30mm, my box=magenta]{BPA Risk Assessment Begins}(-30pt)
  \chronosevent[orange]{2006}[my box=orange]{Categorization of DSL}(-5pt)
  \path [every node/.style={font=\large\bfseries\sffamily}] (chronos start |- current bounding box.north) node (n) [above] {1995} (chronos end |- n) node {2008};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Two versions of your timeline from the code above:

[image: chronos variations]

Comment: This is actually so beautiful, can you please tell me how to add date as dd/mm/yyyy in the box ?

Comment: @Sari Try deleting the key `only text` from the options for the `tikzpicture`. You may need to alter the date format, too.

Comment: This fails on Tex Live 2019, see [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348977/tikz-chronology-year-quarter-timeline/349236#comment1307209_349236).