# how to put the box under another box

Tags: tikz-pgf

why the line of 2008 above the box of 2007? I did not change any code. I want to change the line of 2008 below of the box of 2007.
[Chronosys printing measurement units](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247210/chronosys-printing-measurement-units)

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
%\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}
\usepackage{datenumber,xparse,fp}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,backgrounds,fixedpointarithmetic}
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_chronos_date_tl
\tl_new:N \l_chronos_dateformat_tl
\tl_new:N \l_chronos_year_tl
\tl_new:N \l_chronos_yearformat_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_chronos_dateformat_tl { !d/!m/!Y }
\tl_set:Nn \l_chronos_yearformat_tl { !Y }
% YY yn lle YYYY
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \chronos_year_shorten:n #1
{
  \chronos_year_shorten_aux:w #1 \q_stop % expl3 manuaal, 46
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \chronos_year_shorten_aux:w #1 #2 #3 #4 \q_stop
{
  #3 #4
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \chronos_year_shorten:n { V , c }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_abs:n { c }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn { Nnx }
% dangos dyddiadau
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \chronos_show_date:n #1
{% ateb Joseph Wright: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327642/
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l_chronos_date_tl \l_chronos_dateformat_tl
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_date_tl { !a } { \pgfcalendarweekdayshortname{\thechronos@weekday} }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_date_tl { !A } { \pgfcalendarweekdayname{\thechronos@weekday} }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_date_tl { !b } { \pgfcalendarmonthshortname{\csname chronos@#1month\endcsname} }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_date_tl { !B } { \pgfcalendarmonthname{\csname chronos@#1month\endcsname} }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_date_tl { !d } { \csname chronos@#1day\endcsname }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_date_tl { !E } { \chronos_dateformat_era:c { chronos@#1year } }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_date_tl { !m } { \csname chronos@#1month\endcsname }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_date_tl { !q } { \chronos_dateformat_sign:c { chronos@#1year } }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_date_tl { !Q } { \chronos_dateformat_signs:c { chronos@#1year } }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_date_tl { !y } { \chronos_year_shorten:c { chronos@#1year } }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_date_tl { !Y } { \int_abs:c { chronos@#1year } }
  \l_chronos_date_tl
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \chronos_show_year:n #1
{% ateb Joseph Wright: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327642/
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l_chronos_year_tl \l_chronos_yearformat_tl
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_year_tl { !E } { \chronos_dateformat_era:n { #1 } }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_year_tl { !q } { \chronos_dateformat_sign:n { #1 } }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_year_tl { !Q } { \chronos_dateformat_signs:n { #1 } }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_year_tl { !y } { \chronos_year_shorten:n { #1 } }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnx \l_chronos_year_tl { !Y } { \int_abs:n { #1 } }
  \l_chronos_year_tl
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \chronos_dateformat_sign:n #1
{
  \int_compare:nT { #1 < 0 } { - }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \chronos_dateformat_sign:n { c }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \chronos_dateformat_signs:n #1
{
  \int_compare:nTF
  { #1 < 0 } { - }
  {
    \int_compare:nT { #1 > 0 }
    {
      \ifchronos@yearzero\relax
      \else
        \int_compare:nT { #1 > 1} { +  }
      \fi
    }
  }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \chronos_dateformat_signs:n { c }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \chronos_dateformat_era:n #1
{
  \int_compare:nTF
  { #1 < 0 } { \chronos@yearbce }
  {
    \int_compare:nT { #1 > 0 }
    {
      \ifchronos@yearzero\relax
      \else
        \int_compare:nT { #1 > 1} { \chronos@yearce }
      \fi
    }
  }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \chronos_dateformat_era:n { c }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \chronos_set_dateformat:n #1
{
  \tl_set:Nn \l_chronos_dateformat_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_chronos_dateformat_tl { ~ } { \c_space_token }
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \chronos_set_yearformat:n #1
{
  \tl_set:Nn \l_chronos_yearformat_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_chronos_yearformat_tl { ~ } { \c_space_token }
}
% user interface
\NewDocumentCommand \chronos@setdateformat { m }
{
  \chronos_set_dateformat:n { #1 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand \chronos@setyearformat { m }
{
  \chronos_set_yearformat:n { #1 }
}
% for pgf/tikz convenience
\NewDocumentCommand \chronos@showdate { o m }
{
  \group_begin:
    \IfValueT { #1 }
    {
      \chronos_set_dateformat:n { #1 }
    }
    \pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\csname thechronos@#2date\endcsname}{\c@chronos@weekday}%
    \chronos_show_date:n { #2 }
  \group_end:
}
\NewDocumentCommand \chronos@showyear { o m }
{
  \group_begin:
    \IfValueT { #1 }
    {
      \chronos_set_yearformat:n { #1 }
    }
    \chronos_show_year:n { #2 }
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newlength\chronos@tempdima
\newcounter{chronos@date}
\newcounter{chronos@startdate}
\newcounter{chronos@enddate}
\newcounter{chronos@startyear}
\newcounter{chronos@endyear}
\newcounter{chronos@yeardate}
\newcounter{chronos@thingdate}
\newcounter{chronos@otherthingdate}
\newcounter{chronos@weekday}
\newcounter{chronos@tempcnta}
\newif\ifchronos@marks
\chronos@marksfalse
\newif\ifchronos@timeline@showyears
\chronos@timeline@showyearstrue
\newif\ifchronos@eventyearsonline
\chronos@eventyearsonlinefalse
\newif\ifchronos@yearzero
\chronos@yearzerofalse
\newif\ifchronos@onlytext
\chronos@onlytextfalse
\newif\ifchronos@markeras
\chronos@markerasfalse
\newif\ifchronos@yearsonline
\chronos@yearsonlinefalse
\newif\ifchronos@eventdatessplit
\chronos@eventdatessplitfalse
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format,
  int detect,
  set thousands separator={},
}
\tikzset{%
  /handlers/.chronos too/.code={%
    \edef\chronos@tempc{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}%
    \edef\chronos@tempd{#1}%
    \tikzset{%
      \pgfkeyscurrentpath @too/.code={%
        \tikzset{%
          /chronos/\chronos@tempd/.append style={##1},
        }%
      },
      \chronos@tempc/.forward to=\chronos@tempc @too,
    }%
  },
  chronos/.code={% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159856/ - Claudio Fiandrino
    \tikzset{%
      align=center,
      anchor=mid,
      fixed point arithmetic,
      /chronos/.cd,
      #1,
      timeline config,
      timeline config/.code={},
    }%
    \ifnum\chronos@startyear=\chronos@endyear
      \tikzset{%
        /chronos/timeline no years,
      }%
    \fi
    \setlength\chronos@tempdima{\chronos@timelinemargin}%
    \ifchronos@markeras
      {%
        \chronos@timelinefont
        \pgfmathsetmacro\chronos@tempe{((width("\chronos@bce"))>(width("\chronos@ce"))) ? (width("\chronos@bce")) : (width("\chronos@ce"))}%
        \xdef\chronos@tempf{\chronos@tempe}%
      }%
      \addtolength\chronos@tempdima{\chronos@tempf pt}%
    \fi
    \pgfmathsetmacro\chronos@unit{(\chronos@width-2*\chronos@tempdima)/(\thechronos@enddate-\thechronos@startdate)}%
    \draw [/chronos/timeline@line, line width=\chronos@height] (-\chronos@tempdima,0) coordinate (chronos pre) -- +(\chronos@width,0) coordinate (chronos post);
    \coordinate (chronos base) at (0,-.5*\chronos@height);
    \coordinate (chronos top) at (0,.5*\chronos@height);
    \coordinate (chronos foot) at (0,{-.5*\chronos@height-\chronos@borderheight});
    \coordinate (chronos head) at (0,{.5*\chronos@height+\chronos@borderheight});
    \coordinate (chronos start) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (chronos end) at ([xshift=-\chronos@tempdima]chronos post);
    \ifdim\chronos@borderheight>0pt
      \fill [bottom color=chronos@borderinner, top color=chronos@borderouter] (chronos pre |- chronos head) rectangle (chronos post |- chronos top);
      \fill [top color=chronos@borderinner, bottom color=chronos@borderouter] (chronos pre |- chronos base) rectangle (chronos post |- chronos foot);
    \fi
    \ifchronos@timeline@showyears
      \pgfmathsetcounter{chronos@startyear}{\chronos@startyear}%
      \pgfmathsetcounter{chronos@endyear}{\chronos@endyear}%
      \def\tempa{none}%
      \ifx\chronos@stepfrom\tempa
        \def\tempa{01}%
        \ifx\chronos@startmonth\tempa
          \ifx\chronos@startday\tempa
            \else\stepcounter{chronos@startyear}%
          \fi
          \else\stepcounter{chronos@startyear}%
        \fi
      \else
        \pgfmathsetcounter{chronos@startyear}{\chronos@stepfrom}%
      \fi
      \def\tempa{12}%
      \def\tempb{31}%
      \ifx\chronos@endmonth\tempa
        \ifx\chronos@endday\tempb
          \stepcounter{chronos@endyear}%
        \fi
      \fi
      \ifnum\value{chronos@endyear}<\value{chronos@startyear}\setcounter{chronos@endyear}{\thechronos@startyear}\fi
      \pgfmathsetmacro\chronos@nextstep{int(((\thechronos@startyear+\chronos@stepyears)>\thechronos@endyear) ? \thechronos@endyear : (\thechronos@startyear+\chronos@stepyears))}%
      \ifchronos@yearzero\setcounter{chronos@tempcnta}{1}\else\setcounter{chronos@tempcnta}{0}\fi
      \foreach \b [evaluate=\b as \i using {((\b==0)&&(\thechronos@tempcnta==0)) ? 1 : int(\b)}, remember=\i as \ilast (initially \pi)] in {\thechronos@startyear,\chronos@nextstep,...,\thechronos@endyear} {%
        \ifnum\i=\ilast\relax
        \else
          \pgfcalendardatetojulian{{\i}-01-01}{\c@chronos@yeardate}%
          \ifchronos@yearzero\relax\else\ifnum0<\i\addtocounter{chronos@yeardate}{-366}\fi\fi
          \pgfmathsetmacro\chronos@tempa{(\thechronos@yeardate-\thechronos@startdate)*\chronos@unit}%
          \ifchronos@yearsonline
            \node (chronos@year@\i) [/chronos/.cd, timeline@years, timeline year on line] at (\chronos@tempa pt,0) {\chronos@timelinefont\chronos@showyear{\i}};
            \ifchronos@marks
               \path [/chronos/timeline mark on line] (chronos@year@\i.south) -- (chronos@year@\i |- chronos base);
               \path [/chronos/timeline mark on line] (chronos@year@\i.north) --  (chronos@year@\i |- chronos top);
            \fi
            \ifchronos@markeras
              \path (chronos pre) +(\chronos@timelinemargin,0) node (chronos@bce) [/chronos/.cd, timeline@years, timeline year on line] {\chronos@timelinefont\chronos@bce};
              \path (chronos post) +(-\chronos@timelinemargin,0) node (chronos@ce) [/chronos/.cd, timeline@years, timeline year on line] {\chronos@timelinefont\chronos@ce};
            \fi
          \else
            \node (chronos@year@\i) [/chronos/.cd, timeline@years, timeline year off line] at (\chronos@tempa pt,0) {\chronos@timelinefont\chronos@showyear{\i}};
            \ifchronos@marks
              \path [shorten <=.5*\chronos@height, /chronos/timeline mark off line] (\chronos@tempa pt, 0) -- (chronos@year@\i);
            \fi
            \ifchronos@markeras
              \path (chronos pre) +(\chronos@timelinemargin,0) node (chronos@bce) [/chronos/.cd, timeline@years, timeline year off line] {\chronos@timelinefont\chronos@bce};
              \path (chronos post) +(-\chronos@timelinemargin,0) node (chronos@ce) [/chronos/.cd, timeline@years, timeline year off line] {\chronos@timelinefont\chronos@ce};
            \fi
          \fi
        \fi
      }%
    \else
      \ifchronos@markeras
        \path (chronos pre) +(\chronos@timelinemargin,0) node (chronos@bce) [/chronos/.cd, timeline@years, timeline year off line] {\chronos@timelinefont\chronos@bce};
        \path (chronos post) +(-\chronos@timelinemargin,0) node (chronos@ce) [/chronos/.cd, timeline@years, timeline year off line] {\chronos@timelinefont\chronos@ce};
      \fi
    \fi
    \ifchronos@eventyearsonline
      \tikzset{%
        /chronos/timeline years=on line,
      }%
    \fi
  },
  chronos set date/.code args={#1:#2:#3:#4}{%
    \pgfcalendardatetojulian{{#1}-#2-#3}{\c@chronos@date}%
    \setcounter{chronos@#4date}{\thechronos@date}%
    \ifchronos@yearzero\relax
    \else
      \setcounter{chronos@tempcnta}{#1}%
      \ifnum0<\value{chronos@tempcnta}%
        \addtocounter{chronos@#4date}{-366}%
      \fi
    \fi
    \expandafter\def\csname chronos@#4year\endcsname{#1}%
    \expandafter\def\csname chronos@#4month\endcsname{#2}%
    \expandafter\def\csname chronos@#4day\endcsname{#3}%
  },
  chronos date/.style args={#1-#2-#3}{%
    /tikz/chronos set date/.expanded={#1:#2:#3:thing}%
  },
  chronos period date/.style args={#1-#2-#3}{%
    /tikz/chronos set date/.expanded={#1:#2:#3:otherthing}%
  },
  /chronos/.search also={/tikz},
  /chronos/.cd,
  timeline config/.code={},
  date format/.code={%
    \chronos@setdateformat{#1}%
  },
  year format/.code={%
    \chronos@setyearformat{#1}%
  },
  step years/.store in=\chronos@stepyears,
  step from year/.store in=\chronos@stepfrom,
  start date/.style args={#1-#2-#3}{%
    /chronos/timeline config/.append code={%
      \tikzset{/tikz/chronos set date/.expanded={#1:#2:#3:start}}%
    },
  },
  end date/.style args={#1-#2-#3}{%
    /chronos/timeline config/.append code={%
      \tikzset{/tikz/chronos set date/.expanded={#1:#2:#3:end}}%
    },
  },
  ce year label/.store in=\chronos@yearce,
  bce year label/.store in=\chronos@yearbce,
  timeline ce label/.store in=\chronos@ce,
  timeline bce label/.store in=\chronos@bce,
  timeline width/.store in=\chronos@width,
  timeline height/.store in=\chronos@height,
  width/.forward to=/chronos/timeline width,
  height/.forward to=/chronos/timeline height,
  timeline border height/.store in=\chronos@borderheight,
  timeline border inner colour/.code={\colorlet{chronos@borderinner}{#1}},
  timeline border outer colour/.code={\colorlet{chronos@borderouter}{#1}},
  timeline mark eras/.is if=chronos@markeras,
  timeline margin/.store in=\chronos@timelinemargin,
  timeline font/.store in=\chronos@timelinefont,
  timeline years set/.store in=\chronos@timelineyears,
  timeline years/.is choice,
  timeline years/.forward to=/chronos/timeline years set,
  timeline years/above/.code={%
    \tikzset{%
      /chronos/timeline@years/.style={above, anchor=south, yshift=.5*\chronos@height},
    }%
  },
  timeline years/below/.code={%
    \tikzset{%
      /chronos/timeline@years/.style={below, anchor=north, yshift=-.5*\chronos@height},
    }%
  },
  timeline years/on line/.code={%
    \chronos@yearsonlinetrue
    \tikzset{%
      /chronos/timeline@years/.style={anchor=center},
    }%
  },
  only years/.code={%
    \edef\tempa{}%
    \edef\tempb{#1}%
    \ifx\tempa\tempb\chronos@setdateformat{!Y}\else\chronos@setdateformat{#1}\fi
    \tikzset{%
      /tikz/chronos date/.style={%
        /tikz/chronos set date/.expanded={##1:01:01:thing}%
      },
      /tikz/chronos period date/.style={%
        /tikz/chronos set date/.expanded={##1:01:01:otherthing}%
      },
    }%
  },
  only text/.code={%
    \tikzset{/chronos/only years}%
    \chronos@setdateformat{}%
    \chronos@onlytexttrue
  },
  year zero/.is if=chronos@yearzero,
  background/.code={%
    \colorlet{chronos@background}{#1}%
  },
  timeline marks/.is if=chronos@marks,
  timeline show years/.is if=chronos@timeline@showyears,
  timeline no years/.code={%
    \tikzset{%
      /chronos/timeline show years=false,
    }%
  },
  lines/.style={draw, {Triangle[width=0pt 3,reversed,length=0pt 1.5]}-{Triangle[width=0pt 3,reversed,length=0pt 1.5]}, shorten <={.5*\chronos@height+\chronos@borderheight}},
  events/.style={fill=chronos@background, fill opacity=.75, text opacity=1, draw opacity=1, rounded corners, align=center, font=\footnotesize},
  period/.style={draw},
  period event line/.style={/chronos/lines},
  period event/.style={/chronos/events},
  event line/.style={/chronos/lines},
  event/.style={/chronos/events},
  event years on line/.is if=chronos@eventyearsonline,
  event year on line/.style={/chronos/timeline@years, /chronos/timeline year on line},
  event dates split/.is if=chronos@eventdatessplit,
  event date split/.style={/chronos/event},
  event distance/.store in=\chronos@eventdistance,
  special date/.store in=\chronos@specialdate,
  timeline@line/.style={draw},
  timeline line/.chronos too=timeline@line,
  timeline year off line/.style={fill=chronos@background, text opacity=1, align=center, fill opacity=.75},
  timeline mark off line/.style={draw, {Triangle[width=0pt 3,reversed,length=0pt 1.5]}-, thin, shorten >=-2pt},
  timeline year on line/.style={text=chronos@background, inner sep=1pt, align=center},
  timeline mark on line/.style={draw=chronos@background, shorten >=1.5pt},
  timeline mark too/.code={%
    \tikzset{%
      /chronos/.cd,
      timeline mark on line/.append style={#1},
      timeline mark off line/.append style={#1},
    }%
  },
  timeline year too/.code={%
    \tikzset{%
      /chronos/.cd,
      timeline year on line/.append style={#1},
      timeline year off line/.append style={#1},
    }%
  },
  timeline mark/.forward to=/chronos/timeline mark too,
  timeline year/.forward to=/chronos/timeline year too,
  start date=1001-10-01,
  end date=1003-06-14,
  timeline width=100mm,
  timeline height=1pt,
  timeline border height=0pt,
  chronos date=1850-01-01,
  chronos period date=1851-01-01,
  step years=1,
  timeline years=above,
  background=white,
  timeline border inner colour=black,
  timeline border outer colour=chronos@background,
  step from year=none,
  special date=none,
  ce year label={\textsc{ce}},
  bce year label={\textsc{bce}},
  event distance=-10pt,
  timeline ce label={CE},
  timeline bce label={BCE},
  timeline margin=10pt,
  timeline font=\sffamily,
}
\NewDocumentCommand \chronosevent { O {} m O {} +m D () { \chronos@eventdistance } }
{%
  \tikzset{%
    chronos date/.expanded={#2},
  }%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\chronos@offset{(#5 < 0pt) ? (#5-.5*\chronos@height-\chronos@borderheight) : (#5+.5*\chronos@height+\chronos@borderheight)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\chronos@anchor{(#5 < 0pt) ? "north" : "south"}%
  \scoped[on background layer]{%
    \ifchronos@eventdatessplit
      \ifchronos@onlytext\relax
      \else
        \pgfmathsetmacro\chronos@invanchor{(#5 < 0pt) ? "south" : "north"}%
        \path [postaction={/chronos/event line, #1}] ({(\thechronos@thingdate-\thechronos@startdate)*\chronos@unit pt},0) -- +(0,-\chronos@offset pt) node [anchor=\chronos@invanchor, /chronos/event date split, #3] {\chronos@showdate{thing}};
      \fi
      \path [postaction={/chronos/event line, #1}] ({(\thechronos@thingdate-\thechronos@startdate)*\chronos@unit pt},0) -- +(0,\chronos@offset pt) node [anchor=\chronos@anchor, /chronos/event, #3] {#4};
    \else
      \path [postaction={/chronos/event line, #1}] ({(\thechronos@thingdate-\thechronos@startdate)*\chronos@unit pt},0) -- +(0,\chronos@offset pt) node [anchor=\chronos@anchor, /chronos/event, #3] {\ifchronos@onlytext\relax\else\chronos@showdate{thing}\\\fi#4};
    \fi
  }%
  \ifchronos@eventyearsonline
    \edef\tempa{none}%
    \edef\tempb{\chronos@specialdate}%
    \ifx\tempa\tempb\else\let\chronos@thingyear\chronos@specialdate\tikzset{/chronos/special date=none}\fi
    \node [/chronos/.cd, event year on line] at ({(\thechronos@thingdate-\thechronos@startdate)*\chronos@unit pt},0) {\chronos@thingyear};
  \fi
}
\NewDocumentCommand \chronosspecialdate { m }
{%
  \tikzset{%
    /chronos/special date=#1,
  }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand \chronosperiod { O {} m O {} m O {} +m D () { \chronos@eventdistance } }
{%
  \tikzset{%
    chronos date/.expanded={#2}, chronos period date/.expanded={#4}
  }%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\chronos@offset{(#7 < 0pt) ? (#7-.5*\chronos@height-\chronos@borderheight) : (#7+.5*\chronos@height+\chronos@borderheight)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\chronos@anchor{(#7 < 0pt) ? "north" : "south"}%
  \ifchronos@yearsonline
    \pgfmathsetmacro\chronos@borderoffset{(#7 < 0pt) ? (-.5*\chronos@height-.5*\chronos@borderheight) : (.5*\chronos@height+.5*\chronos@borderheight)}%
    \path [postaction={line width=\chronos@borderheight, /chronos/period, blend mode=overlay, #1}] ({(\thechronos@thingdate-\thechronos@startdate)*\chronos@unit pt},\chronos@borderoffset pt) -- ({(\thechronos@otherthingdate-\thechronos@startdate)*\chronos@unit pt},\chronos@borderoffset pt);
  \else
    \path [postaction={line width=\chronos@height, /chronos/period, #1}] ({(\thechronos@thingdate-\thechronos@startdate)*\chronos@unit pt},0) -- ({(\thechronos@otherthingdate-\thechronos@startdate)*\chronos@unit pt},0);
  \fi
  \scoped[on background layer]{\path [postaction={/chronos/period event line, #3}] ({(.5*\thechronos@otherthingdate+.5*\thechronos@thingdate-\thechronos@startdate)*\chronos@unit pt},0) -- +(0,\chronos@offset pt) node [anchor=\chronos@anchor, /chronos/period event, #5] {\ifchronos@onlytext\relax\else\chronos@showdate{thing}--\chronos@showdate{otherthing}\\\fi#6};}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    chronos={%
      timeline width=100mm,
      start date=2007-01-01,
      end date=2019-01-01,
      events/.append style={text width=20mm},
      timeline font=\footnotesize,
      timeline marks,
      timeline height=5mm,
      only text,
      timeline years=on line,
      timeline border height=5pt,
    },
    my box/.style={draw=#1, rounded corners, text=#1, thick},
  ]
  \chronosevent[blue]{2007}[my box=blue]{Debate on CEPA Begins}(-5pt)
  \chronosevent[green!75!black]{2008}[my box=green!75!black]{CEPA Amendments Passed}(-40pt)
  \chronosevent[magenta]{2009}[text width=30mm, my box=magenta]{\begin{itemize}[before=\color{magenta}\sffamily]
 \item try
 \item try
\end{itemize}
}(-80pt)
  \chronosevent[orange]{2011}[my box=orange]{Categorization of DSL}(-5pt)
  \path [every node/.style={font=\large\bfseries\sffamily}] (chronos start |- current bounding box.north) node (n) [above] {2007} (chronos end |- n) node {2019};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could change the order you are giving the commands, so that the node of 2009 command is given before 2008 and this (2008) before 2007. This would print first the 2009 and after 2008 and after that 2007, and this way their lines will be as you like to be (not tested but this is the way `tikz` works). Edit: by "node" I mean your commands: `\chronosevent`

Comment: I get an error `! LaTeX3 Error: Variant form 'c' deprecated for base form`. Do you get the same error?

Comment: @marmot, I just runed on Overleaf and it doesn't give any error. And on my debian I just ,miss OMS/cmss/o/m

Comment: Welcome! I am writing an answer with this explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tikz shapes, like nodes etc, are usually created in the order that these commands appear in your code. So, If you give first a command:

```
\fill[red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
```

And after that a:

```
\fill[green] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
```

The green rectangle will cover the red one and the first will be printed in your output below the green and thus it will be invisible.

Full code and output:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\fill[green] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you change the order of the above commands you will get the green below the red and so, the part of the green that is not below of the red will be visible and the red will printed over the green and will be visible and whole.

Full code and output:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[green] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\fill[red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thus in your case you have to give the commands:

```
\chronosevent[blue]{2007}[my box=blue]{Debate on CEPA Begins}(-5pt)
  \chronosevent[green!75!black]{2008}[my box=green!75!black]{CEPA Amendments Passed}(-40pt)
  \chronosevent[magenta]{2009}[text width=30mm, my box=magenta]{\begin{itemize}[before=\color{magenta}\sffamily]
```

in the order:

```
\chronosevent[magenta]{2009}[text width=30mm, my box=magenta]{\begin{itemize}[before=\color{magenta}\sffamily]
\chronosevent[green!75!black]{2008}[my box=green!75!black]{CEPA Amendments Passed}(-40pt)
\chronosevent[blue]{2007}[my box=blue]{Debate on CEPA Begins}(-5pt)
```

This way the last (2007) will be printed above the middle (2008) one and the middle
 above the first (2009).