# Intervals on the real line. How to construct the symbolic diagrams of real intervals on the real line?

Tags: diagrams, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, svg

I'm trying to elaborate on my student's exercises on interval notation on the number line.

I tried using the LaTeX code of this response [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333247/very-simple-number-line-with-points/333261) to draw intervals on the number line identical to those in the figure below. But I didn't succeed in doing the black shaded part, or making the circle with white interior, or making the circle with black interior.

Could you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary[arrows.meta]
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
line/.style = {draw,thick, 
               shorten >=-2pt, shorten <=-2pt}
                     ]
\draw (-3,0) -- (7,0);
\foreach \i in {-3,-2,...,7} % numbers on line
\draw (\i,0.15) -- ++ (0,-0.3) node[below] {$\i$}; % tick and their labels

\draw[line, {Circle[length=4pt]}-{Circle[length=4pt, fill=white]}]  (1,0) -- (2,0);
\draw[line, {Circle[length=4pt, fill=white]}-{Circle[length=4pt]}]  (3,0) -- (4,0);
\draw[line, {Circle[length=4pt]}-{Triangle[length=4pt]}]  (5,0) -- (7,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For any kind of interval you can define own styles, where are defined line options, i.e. contain option now written in `\draw` options:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
line/.style = {draw,thick, shorten <=-2pt},
  La/.style = {line, shorten >=-2pt, 
               {Circle[length=4pt]}-{Circle[length=4pt, fill=white]}},
  Lb/.style = {line, shorten >=-2pt,
               {Circle[length=4pt, fill=white]}-{Circle[length=4pt]}},
  Lc/.style = {line, 
               {Circle[length=4pt, fill=white]}-{Triangle[length=4pt]}},
                     ]
\draw (-3,0) -- (7,0);
\foreach \i in {-3,-2,...,7} % numbers on line
\draw (\i,0.15) -- ++ (0,-0.3) node[below] {$\i$}; % tick and their labels

\draw[La]  (1,0) -- (2,0);
\draw[Lb]  (3,0) -- (4,0);
\draw[Lc]  (5,0) -- (7,0);
\draw[Lc]  (-1,0) -- (-3,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** I try to consider OP comment. Since it is not very clear to me, the following suggestion is based on guessing. If you like to have number line is in gray, just add option `gray`, for  intervals thicker. If like thicker interval lines, instead `thick` you can experiment with `ultra thick`. If this is still to tiny for you, you can replace it with `line width=<desired width>`.

An example, which try to consider OP comment is:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
line/.style = {draw, ultra thick, shorten <=-2pt},
  La/.style = {line, shorten >=-2pt,
               {Circle[length=4pt, line width=1pt]}-{Circle[length=4pt,line width=1pt, fill=white]}},
  Lb/.style = {line, shorten >=-2pt,
               {Circle[length=4pt, line width=1pt, fill=white]}-{Circle[length=4pt, line width=1pt]}},
  Lc/.style = {line,
               {Circle[length=4pt, line width=1pt, fill=white]}-{Triangle[length=4pt, line width=1pt]}},
                     ]
\draw[gray] (-3,0) -- (7,0);    % <---
\foreach \i in {-3,-2,...,7} % numbers on line
\draw[gray] (\i,0.15) -- ++ (0,-0.3)    % <---
    node[below,text=black] {$\i$}; % tick and their labels

\draw[La]  (1,0) -- (2,0);
\draw[Lb]  (3,0) -- (4,0);
\draw[Lc]  (5,0) -- (7,0);
\draw[Lc]  (-1,0) -- (-3,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Tanks!+1 Would it have to increase the width of the line to 4 pt and fix the color of the line in gray? How to almentar and the width of the ranges for 6pt or 8pt fix the color in black?

Comment: @MathOverview, see edited answer. Is now what you after?