# \addmilestone in Tikz not placing milestone in correct point

Tags: tikz-pgf, timeline

Here is a MWE. The `\addmilestones` that are commented out in the MWE are the problem. The actual dates that I need are presented at the end of each `\addmilestone` command. Also the color of the bubbles should be varying shades of red commensurate with the size of the bubble. Small bubble =light red, biggest bubble = blood red.

The `timeline` library can be found at https://github.com/cfiandra/timeline

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{timeline}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[timespan={}]
% timespan={Day} -> now we have days as reference
% timespan={}    -> no label is displayed for the timespan
% default timespan is 'Week'

\timeline[custom interval=true]{1966, 1971, 1979, 1980, 1981,1986,1996,2001,2006,2011,2016}
% \timeline[custom interval=true]{3,...,9} -> i.e., from Day 3 to Day 9
% \timeline{8} -> i.e., from Week 1 to Week 8

% put here the phases
\begin{phases}
\initialphase{involvement degree=0cm,phase color=black}
\phase{between week=1 and 1 in 0.5,involvement degree=1.65cm}
\phase{between week=2 and 3 in 0.5,involvement degree=3.5cm}
\phase{between week=3 and 4 in 0.5,involvement degree=0cm}
\phase{between week=4 and 5 in 0.5,involvement degree=0cm}
\phase{between week=5 and 6 in 0.5,involvement degree=0}
\phase{between week=5 and 6 in 0.5,involvement degree=2.5cm} Guerilla
\phase{between week=6 and 7 in 0.5,involvement degree=1.9cm}
\phase{between week=7 and 8 in 0.5,involvement degree=3cm}
\phase{between week=8 and 9 in 0.5,involvement degree =1.7cm}
\end{phases}

% put here the milestones
\addmilestone{at=phase-0.270,direction=270:2cm,text={Obote/UPC win First Multiparty elections},text options={below}} %1962
\addmilestone{at=phase-1.110,direction=90:2cm,text={Obote attacks President Mutesa palace},text options={above}}
\addmilestone{at=phase-2.110,direction=90:1.5cm,text={Idi Amin's Reign of Terror},text options={above}}
\addmilestone{at=phase-6.270,direction=270:1cm,text={Museveni Bush War},text options={below}}
\addmilestone{at=phase-7.110,direction=110:1.5cm,text={Northern Uganda War I},text options={above}}
\addmilestone{at=phase-8.90,direction=90:1.5cm,text={Northern Uganda War II},text options={above}}
\addmilestone{at=phase-9.60,direction=60:1.5cm,text={Northern Uganda War III},text options={above}}
%These are the problematic milestones I cannot get them placed at individual point dates, eg. 1966, 1971 etc...
%\addmilestone{at=phase-8.250,direction=240:1.5cm,text={Obote abrogates Constitution },text options={below}} %  1966
%\addmilestone{at=phase-8.250,direction=240:1.5cm,text={Idi Amin overthrows Obote },text options={below}} % 1971
%\addmilestone{at=phase-8.250,direction=240:1.5cm,text={Multiparty elections. Obote wins },text options={below}} % 1980
%\addmilestone{at=phase-6.170,direction=170:1.5cm,text={Museveni starts Bush war},text options={below}} % 1981
%\addmilestone{at=phase-6.170,direction=170:1.5cm,text={Okellos overthrow Obote II},text options={below}} 1985
%\addmilestone{at=phase-6.170,direction=170:1.5cm,text={Museveni seizes power from Okellos},text options={below}} 1986
%\addmilestone{at=phase-8.250,direction=240:1.5cm,text={``No party'' elections. Museveni wins },text options={below}} % 1996
%\addmilestone{at=phase-8.250,direction=240:1.5cm,text={``No party'' elections, Museveni wins },text options={below}} % 2001
%\addmilestone{at=phase-8.250,direction=240:1.5cm,text={Multiparty elections, Museveni wins },text options={below}} % 2006

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ladies and Gents! Any help with this question TEXperts? Please!

Comment: Anyone know how to contact the creator of timeline package? Should be trivial for her/him to fix.

Comment: hmmmm...grrrrrr

Comment: Regarding contacting the author: It is not a standard library, but Google was helpful enough to point to https://github.com/cfiandra/timeline, where you can create a new issue, and further to http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159856/13304 where it originated from.

Comment: I hadn't seen your question before now, by the way. If you don't get any sort of response, you have some options, but adding more comments is likely the least helpful. You could for example do some minor-but-useful edit to push it to the top of the front page. If you have points to spare you can add a bounty. Or, you could ask [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) if anyone could have a look.

Comment: Why do you think there's something to fix?

Answer (score 3):

Not entirely sure I understand correctly, but the nodes that holds the years are named as `\timespan-\xi`, where `\timespan` is what you define in `timespan={}` (i.e. nothing, in your case), and `\xi` is a counter that starts from 1. Hence, the 1966-node for example is called `-1`, so you could put your milestone at e.g. `-1.south`. I did the first two as an example, but you can fill in the rest yourself. I don't know how you'd like to place the text anyway:

[image: output of code]

You might notice that the circle for the milestone is not exactly centered under the year. The reason for that is an explicit space in the node text, as you can see from lines [98 and 102 in `tikzlibrarytimeline.code.tex`](https://github.com/cfiandra/timeline/blob/67c9f0e362452beabbecf49bc9c47e3970dc222a/tikzlibrarytimeline.code.tex). Adding `draw=white` to the node options demonstrates this:

[image]

You can however patch the `\timeline` macro to remove the space, with

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\timeline}{\timespan\ \x}{\x}{}{}
```

I don't have an answer for the color part.

Complete code with patch applied:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{timeline}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\timeline}{\timespan\ \x}{\x}{}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[timespan={}]
% timespan={Day} -> now we have days as reference
% timespan={}    -> no label is displayed for the timespan
% default timespan is 'Week'

\timeline[custom interval=true]{1966, 1971, 1979, 1980, 1981,1986,1996,2001,2006,2011,2016}
% \timeline[custom interval=true]{3,...,9} -> i.e., from Day 3 to Day 9
% \timeline{8} -> i.e., from Week 1 to Week 8

% put here the phases
\begin{phases}
\initialphase{involvement degree=0cm,phase color=black}
\phase{between week=1 and 1 in 0.5,involvement degree=1.65cm}
\phase{between week=2 and 3 in 0.5,involvement degree=3.5cm}
\phase{between week=3 and 4 in 0.5,involvement degree=0cm}
\phase{between week=4 and 5 in 0.5,involvement degree=0cm}
\phase{between week=5 and 6 in 0.5,involvement degree=0}
\phase{between week=5 and 6 in 0.5,involvement degree=2.5cm} 
\phase{between week=6 and 7 in 0.5,involvement degree=1.9cm}
\phase{between week=7 and 8 in 0.5,involvement degree=3cm}
\phase{between week=8 and 9 in 0.5,involvement degree =1.7cm}
\end{phases}

% put here the milestones
\addmilestone{at=phase-0.270,direction=270:2cm,text={Obote/UPC win First Multiparty elections},text options={below}} %1962
\addmilestone{at=phase-1.110,direction=90:2cm,text={Obote attacks President Mutesa palace},text options={above}}
\addmilestone{at=phase-2.110,direction=90:1.5cm,text={Idi Amin's Reign of Terror},text options={above}}
\addmilestone{at=phase-6.270,direction=270:1cm,text={Museveni Bush War},text options={below}}
\addmilestone{at=phase-7.110,direction=110:1.5cm,text={Northern Uganda War I},text options={above}}
\addmilestone{at=phase-8.90,direction=90:1.5cm,text={Northern Uganda War II},text options={above}}
\addmilestone{at=phase-9.60,direction=60:1.5cm,text={Northern Uganda War III},text options={above}}
%These are the problematic milestones I cannot get them placed at individual point dates, eg. 1966, 1971 etc...
\addmilestone{at=-1.south,direction=240:1.5cm,text={Obote abrogates Constitution },text options={below}} %  1966
\addmilestone{at=-2.south,direction=270:1.cm,text={Idi Amin overthrows Obote },text options={below}} % 1971
%\addmilestone{at=phase-8.250,direction=240:1.5cm,text={Multiparty elections. Obote wins },text options={below}} % 1980
%\addmilestone{at=phase-6.170,direction=170:1.5cm,text={Museveni starts Bush war},text options={below}} % 1981
%\addmilestone{at=phase-6.170,direction=170:1.5cm,text={Okellos overthrow Obote II},text options={below}} 1985
%\addmilestone{at=phase-6.170,direction=170:1.5cm,text={Museveni seizes power from Okellos},text options={below}} 1986
%\addmilestone{at=phase-8.250,direction=240:1.5cm,text={``No party'' elections. Museveni wins },text options={below}} % 1996
%\addmilestone{at=phase-8.250,direction=240:1.5cm,text={``No party'' elections, Museveni wins },text options={below}} % 2001
%\addmilestone{at=phase-8.250,direction=240:1.5cm,text={Multiparty elections, Museveni wins },text options={below}} % 2006

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```