# Line breaks and multiple events on the same date with LaTeX's Chronology package

Tags: chronology

The following MWE has two problems:

1. Events on the same day do not display properly.
2. I don't know how to introduce a line break

The second problem is interesting as it could be a solution to the first problem.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chronology}
\begin{document}
\begin{chronology}*[2]{2007}{2017}{\the\linewidth}
\event{\decimaldate{01}{03}{2010}}{first event}
\event{\decimaldate{01}{03}{2010}}{second event}
\event{\decimaldate{01}{03}{2014}}{this is a very long description that I\\ want to break manually}
\end{chronology}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use a so badly documented package. Check chronosys, or the code of cfr here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125548/how-to-specify-start-and-end-date-of-chronoperiode-in-a-dd-mm-yyyy-format/

Comment: I agree to the basically non-existent documentation, however, I simply like the design and simplicity of chronology.

Comment: Try `\tikzset{eventlabel/.append style={align=center}}`. I think this is better than `chronosys`, actually, though it certainly contains some basic muck ups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My code can do simple styles, too, actually. However, `chronology` can, at least, be adapted in ways which `chronosys` simply resists. Note that it does some dodgy things in the style file, for all that, though.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chronology,geometry}
\tikzset{flippedeventlabel/.append style={align=center}}
\begin{document}
\begin{chronology}*[2]{2007}{2017}{\the\linewidth}
\event{\decimaldate{01}{03}{2010}}{first event}
\event{\decimaldate{01}{03}{2010}}{second event}
\event{\decimaldate{01}{03}{2014}}{this is a very long description that I\\ want to break manually}
\end{chronology}
\end{document}
```

[image: multi-line event]

Do the same for `eventlabel` if not 'flipping' the timeline.