# Unable to add a time period between specific dates in Chronosys

Tags: chronosys

I am using the Chronosys package to create a timeline for a project I am working on. When I add a `\chronoperiode{start}{end}{name}`, and have integer values for start and end, everything works fine. However, if my start or end value is a specific date, like `1/1/1100` or the first of January 1100 I get the error "Missing number, treated as zero". I have tried my usual Tex editor of MiKTeX with VSCode, and overleaf however both produce the same error. I have also checked if the dates themselves are producing the issue, however if I give them to a `\chronoevent{date}{label}` they work just fine. Here is my minimal code that produces the error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chronosys}
\begin{document}
  Hello \LaTeX{} World 
  \startchronology
  \chronoperiode{10}{1000}{Test with integer dates}
  \chronoperiode{1/1/1000}{1/1/1500}{Test with specific dates}
  \endchronology
\end{document}
```

If you put a % before the second period, it compiles, however once you remove it you should get the error. All help is appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: There are missing brackets at: `\end document` -> `\end{document}`.

Comment: It seems that `chronoperiode` only works with years as parameter. For a large period of time, the difference would not be visible anyway. `\chronoevent` can also have a specific date as parameter. See manual of `chronosys`.

Comment: Please don't use `minimal` for examples - it isn't what it is meant for. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125548/how-to-specify-start-and-end-date-of-chronoperiode-in-a-dd-mm-yyyy-format?rq=1. Your best option is to use a different package or draw it in tikz. Alternatively, you could email `chronosys`'s author, who has sometimes spun modified versions for users who ask. The chances of anybody else modifying `chronosys` for you are slim.