# dd/mm/yyyy format on chronosys periods

Tags: timeline, chronosys

The chronosys library allows the `dd/mm/yyyy` format for the `\chronoevent` command, but not `\chronoperiode`. According to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130178/193823) the functionality should be available. It is not.

---

How could I modify the code of the following timeline as for the `Example` period to end at, say, `01/07/2011`?

```
\startchronology
[startyear=2010,stopyear=2012, 
color=lightgray, height=1ex,width=\hsize, 
dates=false, arrow=false]
\chronoperiode[startdate=false, 
stopdate=false, color=red, bottomdepth=0pt, 
topheight=1ex, textdepth=10pt]{2011} 
{2012}{Example}
\stopchronology
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide compilable code. However, `chronosys` is notoriously resistant to customisation. If it should work, but doesn't, I'd suggest contacting the author. Even if it isn't supposed to work, the author has responded positively to requests in the past. The alternative is to use something other than `chronosys`, because that will be much easier than trying to modify the package code.

Comment: Did you try the modified version on GitHub? The post you linked doesn't claim the standard package can do it, although the comment beneath suggests it might now be on CTAN.